# Why is one approach for backtracking faster than the other?

Tags: ruby, recursion, dynamic-programming, backtracking, memoization

So I was working on Leetcode on [Word Breaking II](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break-ii/), and came up with two backtracking implementations that are similar but differ in memoization. However, one will pass the specs while the other would not due to time limit exceeded. Can someone please explain why approach 1 is faster than approach 2?

For context, basically the problem gives me a string and a dictionary. If there are words in the string that are also in the dictionary, separate out the words with a space and place the resulting string (of words) into a resulting array. Dictionary words can be used more than once!

So for example:

```
s = "pineapplepenapple"
wordDict = ["apple", "pen", "applepen", "pine", "pineapple"]
Output:
[
  "pine apple pen apple",
  "pineapple pen apple",
  "pine applepen apple"
]
Explanation: Note that you are allowed to reuse a dictionary word.
```

Approach 1 (works!):

```
require 'set'

def word_break(s, word_dict)
    word_dict = Set.new(word_dict)

    bt(s, word_dict, 0, {})
end

def bt(s, word_dict, i, mem)
    return mem[i] if mem[i]
    return [''] if i == s.length

    res = []

    j = i

    while j < s.length
        word = s[i..j]

        if word_dict.include?(word)
            word_breaks = bt(s, word_dict, j + 1, mem)
 
            word_breaks.each do |words|
                new_combined_words = word
                new_combined_words += ' ' + words if words.length > 0

                res << new_combined_words
            end
        end

        j += 1
    end

    # Memoizing here makes it fast!
    mem[i] = res
end
```

Approach 2 (Not fast enough):

```
require 'set'

def word_break(s, word_dict)
    word_dict = Set.new(word_dict)

    bt(s, word_dict, 0, {})
end

def bt(s, word_dict, i, mem)
    return mem[i] if mem[i]
    return [''] if i== s.length

    res = []

    j = i

    while j < s.length
        word = s[i..j]

        if word_dict.include?(word)
            word_breaks = bt(s, word_dict, j + 1, mem)
 
            word_breaks.each do |words|
                new_combined_words = word
                new_combined_words += ' ' + words if words.length > 0
                
                # Memoizing here but it's too slow
                (mem[i] ||= []) << new_combined_words
                
                res << new_combined_words
            end
        end

        j += 1
    end
    
    res
end
```

In approach 1, I memoize in the end with `mem[i] = res` while in approach 2, I memoize on the fly as I am generating new combination of words.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Readers should not have to search for a URL to understand the problem you are trying to solve. Please provide a link and, preferably, a brief summary of the problem. It would also be helpful if you could introduce each block of code with a short explanation of the approach you are taking.

Comment: Note you can replace the `if-else-end` with `(mem[i] ||= []) << new_combined_words`. I suggest you add `require 'set'`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for all of your suggestions, I have made your recommended edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `mem[i]` happen to be empty array, you would never set it in approach 2. Empty values are not memoized.

<s>What Cary suggested in his comment should fix this. The code is still going to be a bit slower than approach 1, but it will probably pass the tests on leetcode.</s>

UPD: even with that suggested edit, when `bt(s, word_dict, j + 1, mem)` returns an empty array, we would never memoize `mem[i]`, which is makes the code asymptotically exponential. To fix this, try the following.

```
         mem[i] ||= []
        
         if word_dict.include?(word)
            word_breaks = bt(s, word_dict, j + 1, mem)
 

            word_breaks.each do |words|
                new_combined_words = word
                new_combined_words += ' ' + words if words.length > 0

                mem[i] << new_combined_words
                
                res << new_combined_words
            end
        end
```

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it unfortunately, still Time Limit Exceeded. I agree that Cary's suggestion can dry up the code but the principle is the same isn't it? Still not exactly sure why memoizing there is slower than memoizing in the end.

Comment: Wow this seemed to work, thank you so much! So by empty array, you mean literally `[]` and not `['']` correct?

Comment: Here's a test case to reproduce the problem with memoization: `word_break('b'*100+'a', ['b', 'bb'])`

Comment: Hmm, what if the test case is `word_break('a'*100, ['a', 'aa', 'aaa'])`? How does any recursive call bring about an empty array? My original approach 2 would fail in this, even though I don't believe an empty array will be returned (I could be wrong though). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment intended to shed light on the problem. I benchmarked the two methods and was unable to reproduce the result that #1 is faster than #2. `word_break1` (which calls `bt1`) is #1; `word_break2` (which calls `bt2`) is #2.

```
s = "nowisthetimetohavesomefun"
word_dict = %w|now is the time to have some fun no wist he so mefun ist he ti me|
```

```
require 'benchmark'
```

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("#1") { word_break1(s, word_dict) }
  x.report("#2") { word_break2(s, word_dict) }
end
```

The following results were obtained from several runs.

```
       user     system      total        real
#1  0.000342   0.000083   0.000425 (  0.000312)
#2  0.000264   0.000066   0.000330 (  0.000242)*

#1  0.000315   0.000075   0.000390 (  0.000288)
#2  0.000230   0.000066   0.000296 (  0.000208)*

#1  0.000292   0.000079   0.000371 (  0.000268)
#2  0.000255   0.000065   0.000320 (  0.000253)*

#1  0.000292   0.000090   0.000382 (  0.000261)*
#2  0.000337   0.000121   0.000458 (  0.000349)

#1  0.000301   0.000063   0.000364 (  0.000291)*
#2  0.000413   0.000134   0.000547 (  0.000385)

#1  0.000306   0.000079   0.000385 (  0.000280)
#2  0.000281   0.000082   0.000363 (  0.000255)*
```

Both methods return the following array.

```
["no wist he ti me to have so me fun", "no wist he ti me to have so mefun",
 "no wist he ti me to have some fun", "no wist he time to have so me fun",
 "no wist he time to have so mefun", "no wist he time to have some fun",
 "now is the ti me to have so me fun", "now is the ti me to have so mefun",
 "now is the ti me to have some fun", "now is the time to have so me fun",
 "now is the time to have so mefun", "now is the time to have some fun",
 "now ist he ti me to have so me fun", "now ist he ti me to have so mefun",
 "now ist he ti me to have some fun", "now ist he time to have so me fun",
 "now ist he time to have so mefun", "now ist he time to have some fun"]
```